# Find all words enclosed within @{{Word}}@ or {{Word}} from string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am writing code to extract all the words enclosed within @{{}}@ and {{}}, so far I have searched the web and found the below code which works as expected.

```
string sampleString = "A @{{Quick}}@ brown @{{fox}}@ jumps @{{over}}@ a lazy {{dog}}.";
List<string> keywordList = new List<string>();
MatchCollection matchedCollection = Regex.Matches(sampleString, @"(@{{(.*?)}}@|{{(.*?)}})");

foreach (Match m in matchedCollection)
{
    keywordList.Add(m.ToString());
}
```

Above code works fine, it gives me 4 items listed below and that is correct.

1. @{{Quick}}@
2. @{{Fox}}@
3. @{{Over}}@
4. {{dog}}

But, the problem arises when the word is not properly enclosed in the brackets/pattern. For example, if I have improperly formatted string like below, I'll get incorrect result.

```
string sampleString = "A @{{Quick}}@ brown @{{fox jumps @{{over}}@ a lazy {{dog}}.";
```

Code with above string input will give me three items in list.

Current Result:

1. @{{Quick}}@
2. @{{fox jumps @{{over}}@
3. {{dog}}

Expected Result

1. @{{Quick}}@
2. @{{over}}@
3. {{dog}}

Any suggestion to correct this would be really appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest that what you have is fine and any issues, like your example, should be dealt with by cleaning the data.

Comment: Depending on the definition, `@{{fox jumps @{{over}}@` is correct. Unless with "word" you mean `\S` (anything not space) instead of `.` (any character)

Comment: I think in your example, you can replace the dot `.` with [^{]

Comment: Hi @xanatos, I replaced `.` with `\S` and it worked. My keyword will not have any space so this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is words-without-spaces inside, then you can use `\S` instead of `.` (any character that isn't a space instead of any character)

```
MatchCollection matchedCollection = Regex.Matches(sampleString, @"(@{{(\S*?)}}@|{{(\S*?)}})");
```

Answer (score 0):

The repetition in the regex seems redundant, unless you really care to know whether the @ were present or not. If you're stripping them off then `Regex.Matches(sampleString, @"{{(\S*?)}}")` will be fine

Answer (score 0):

If the double curly braces should be exact 2, you can use lookarounds to assert that there are no more curly braces before and after.

```
(@?)(?<!{){{(?!{)\S+?(?<!})}}(?!})\1
```

**Explanation**

- `(@?)` Capture group 1, match an optional `@`
- `(?<!{){{(?!{)` Match `{{` not preceded or followed by `{`
- `\S+?` Match  1+ times as least as possible non whitespace chars
- `(?<!})}}(?!})` Match `}}` not preceded or followed by `}`
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%40%3f%29%28%3f%3c!%7b%29%7b%7b%28%3f!%7b%29%5cS%2b%3f%28%3f%3c!%7d%29%7d%7d%28%3f!%7d%29%5c1&i=%40%7b%7bQuick%7d%7d%40%0d%0a%40%7b%7bFox%7d%7d%40%0d%0a%40%7b%7bOver%7d%7d%40%0d%0a%7b%7bdog%7d%7d%0d%0a%7b%7b%7b%7bdog%7d%7d%0d%0a%0d%0aA+%40%7b%7bQuick%7d%7d%40+brown+%40%7b%7bfox+jumps+%40%7b%7bover%7d%7d%40+a+lazy+%7b%7bdog%7d%7d.%0d%0a%0d%0a%7b%7b%7d%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a%7b%7btesttest%7dtest%7d%7d%40)

If it is no problem to have more than 2 curly braces, you can omit the lookarounds

```
(@?){{\S+?}}\1
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%40%3f%29%7b%7b%5cS%2b%3f%7d%7d%5c1&i=%40%7b%7bQuick%7d%7d%40%0d%0a%40%7b%7bFox%7d%7d%40%0d%0a%40%7b%7bOver%7d%7d%40%0d%0a%7b%7bdog%7d%7d%0d%0a%0d%0aA+%40%7b%7bQuick%7d%7d%40+brown+%40%7b%7bfox+jumps+%40%7b%7bover%7d%7d%40+a+lazy+%7b%7bdog%7d%7d.)

Comment: Really want to know how to write a rule can handle this string ```A @{{Quick}}@ brown @{{foxjumps@{{over}}@ a lazy {{dog}}.```. I am trying to use forward pattern but can't do it. Can you help this? thanks a lot.

Comment: @MichaelMao Do you mean like this? `(@?)(?<!{){{(?!{)(?:(?!{{)\S)+?(?<!})}}(?!})\1` https://regex101.com/r/kQh2h8/1

Comment: Tank you. Looks great but is too complex to understand for me now.

Comment: What I think is don't use the ```\S``` and use the ```.*?``` but exclude the ```@{{``` after first ```@{{``` and before first ```}}@```

Comment: My rule is ```(@{{(.*?)(?!@{{)}}@)``` means can't have two ```@{{``` before a ```}}@```

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry if your matches contain spaces or not, use a proper regex like

```cs
(@)?{{(?:(?!@{{).)*?}}(?(1)@|)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XWvYNp/1).

**C# code**:

```cs
var matchedCollection = Regex.Matches(sampleString, @"(@)?{{(?:(?!@{{).)*?}}(?(1)@|)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @{{                      '@{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character (including \n
                             with RegexOptions.Singleline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }}                       '}}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?(1)                    if back-reference \1 matched, then:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        else:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             succeed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of conditional on \1
```